# Splitting list by keyword

Tags: python, split

I have a list as follows:

```
['MARK_A', 8, 7702.5, 13, 7703, 983472],
['MARK_B', 10, 7702.5, 983472],
['MARK_B', 3, 7703.5, 983472],
['MARK_B', 6, 7701.2, 983472],
['MARK_B', 5, 7704.4, 983472],
['MARK_A', 9, 7701.5, 11, 7704, 983475],
['MARK_B', 10, 7702.5, 983475],
['MARK_B', 3, 7703.5, 983475],
['MARK_B', 6, 7701.2, 983475],
['MARK_B', 5, 7704.4, 983475]]
```

How is it possible to split this list into 2 lists like as follows:

```
[['MARK_A', 8, 7702.5, 13, 7703, 983472],
['MARK_B', 10, 7702.5, 983472],
['MARK_B', 3, 7703.5, 983472],
['MARK_B', 6, 7701.2, 983472],
['MARK_B', 5, 7704.4, 983472]],
[ ['MARK_A', 9, 7701.5, 11, 7704, 983475],
['MARK_B', 10, 7702.5, 983475],
['MARK_B', 3, 7703.5, 983475],
['MARK_B', 6, 7701.2, 983475],
['MARK_B', 5, 7704.4, 983475]]
```

There can be any number of "MARK_A" in list followed by one or more "MARK_B". I would be dividing the lists by the [-1] element

Comment: It always starts at a MARK_A right?

Comment: Always starts with MARK_A yes. It would be ideal though to split by the last element if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I use `itertools.groupby` for this kind of problems(got a collection of collections, split it by tokens in inner collections)

```
from itertools import groupby

class GroupbyHelper:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, item):
        self.count += (item[0] == self.token)
        return self.count


grouped_collections = \
[list(grouped) for _, grouped in groupby(collections, GroupbyHelper("MARK_A"))]
```

somewhat generalized version of above code:

```
from itertools import groupby

class GroupbyHelper:
    def __init__(self, check_token):
        self.check_token = check_token
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, item):
        self.count += self.check_token(item)
        return self.count


grouped_collections = \
[list(grouped) for _, grouped in 
 groupby(collections, GroupbyHelper(lambda x: x[0] == "MARK_A"))]
```

using two iterators:

```
from itertools import tee, zip_longest

iter1, iter2 = tee(i for i, item in enumerate(collections) if item[0] == 'MARK_A')
next(iter2) #advance the second iterator so we can move by range

grouped_collections = \
[collections[s:e] for s, e in zip_longest(iter1, iter2, fillvalue=len(collections))]
```

sometimes a plain for loop isn't that bad:

```
grouped_collections = []
for lst in collections:
    if lst[0]=="MARK_A":
        grouped_collections.append([lst])
    else:
        grouped_collections[-1].append(lst)
```

Comment: Remove the `bool` call. It's okay to treat them like `int`s, and it's already a `bool` anyway. Otherwise a very clever solution

Comment: @jamylak yeah it isn't necessary, but sometimes when I read my old codes `A += B == C` somewhat confuses me. it is okay to remove `bool(a==b)`.

Comment: one other small thing, it's probably best not to call your variable `collections` since it is the name of a module

Comment: is there any alternative to zip_longest?

Comment: @user1862895 what do you mean by 'an alternative'? anyway `zip_longest` is `izip_longest` in python 2.

Comment: syntax error on:grouped_collections = [test[s:e] for s, e in izip_longest(iter1, iter2, fillvalue=len(test)]

Comment: @user1862895 sorry there was an missing parentheses. it should have been `izip_longest(iter1, iter2, fillvalue=len(test))` (missing parantheses after `len(test)`)

Comment: @user1862895 I'd go with the first solution though

Comment: thanks, going with the plain loop above. that worked. couldn't get the class to work. will come back when have whole problem solved. thanks again.