# Split a list into nested list at points where item matches criteria

Tags: python, list, split

I would like to split a list at points where an item is over a certain length.

a simplified version of my data is:

```
li = [1,2,3,4000,5,6,7,8,9000,10,11,12,1300]
```

the outcome I am trying to achieve is as below

```
new_li = [[1,2,3],[4000,5,6,7,8],[9000,10,11,12,1300]]
```

I am new to programming and a little stumped on the approach to this problem.

I am considering looping through and creating an index each time an items length is greater than 2 but am lost as to how I would recreate the nested lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "an items length is greater than 2"?

Comment: I think the trouble you're getting is that your specification is a total fail. When I compare `li` and `new_li` I can see no algorithmical pattern emerging from those two lists.

Comment: I'm confused. I'm guessing you want to split the list when the length of a number (string?) is greater than two? If that is the case, why isnt 1300 in a list on its own?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
li = [1,2,3,4000,5,6,7,8,9000,10,11,12,1300]
r = [[]]  # start with a list containing an empty sub-list
for i in li:
  if i >= 2000:
    # start a new sub-list when we see a big value
    r.append([i])
  else: 
    # append to the last sub-list of r
    r[-1].append(i)
```

Comment: that could be an idea, but it would then generate `[[1,2,3],[4000,5,6,7,8],[9000,10,11,12],[1300]]`

Comment: I corrected it to 2000.  But the question is pretty unclear just where they want to split.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby

li = [1,2,3,4000,5,6,7,8,9000,10,11,12,1300]

class GroupbyHelper(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.i = 0

    def __call__(self, val):
        self.i += (val > self.val)
        return self.i


>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(li, key=GroupbyHelper(2000))]
[[1, 2, 3], [4000, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9000, 10, 11, 12, 1300]]
```

Comment: This seems kinda overcomplicated, especially for a questioner new to programming.

Comment: I thought about groupby -- but I didn't think about using a simple class to keep the state...Interesting approach.

Comment: @mgilson I copied it off some other guy on here from a similar question which I don't remember. Edit: I found it http://stackoverflow.com/a/16052389/1219006

Comment: @poolie actually I think your approach is simpler but I'll leave this here

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly be more efficient to use slices instead of re-appending each item:

```
li = [1,2,3,4000,5,6,7,8,9000,10,11,12,1300]
res = []
indices = (i for i, v in enumerate(li) if v > 2000)
i = 0
for i2 in indices:
    res.append(li[i:i2])
    i = i2
res.append(li[i:])
```

### edit

Much shorter version:

```
li = [1,2,3,4000,5,6,7,8,9000,10,11,12,1300]
indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(li) if v > 2000]
res = [li[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])]
```

Comment: Python lists can't share structure, so creating it from a slice is not a lot faster than just building it one item at a time, and this builds several other big lists.  On `li * 1000000`, your code takes 7.0s and [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17064533/243712) takes 5.2s on my X201 i7 laptop.

Comment: If you expected `li` would be very long and there would be few lists I can just imagine it might be worth computing the indexes and then slicing.  But generally speaking I think direct imperative looping code in Python is often faster and simpler than fancy functional code; it's just not a natural fit for the vm.